# why doesn't this MIPS file print to the log?

Tags: assembly, mips

For context, I am a student doing a second undergrad.  I am trying to test out of an intro to CS class, because it's mostly Python, which I don't need introductory instruction on, but the course contains a week of instruction on MIPS.  My only way of understanding the universe of things I'm meant to understand is looking at old finals.  I've been watching YouTube videos to try to get some MIPS basics.

Here is a question I'm working on understanding.

> a) What is printed by the MIPS program below?
>
> b) Modify the program to print out 100 copies of the letter ’Z’. Shade in the box for each line that needs to be changed and rewrite the instruction below

```
ADDI $sp, $sp, -11 # Set up stack 
ADDI $s3, $zero, 1 # Store 1 in a registrar 
ADDI $t0, $zero, 90 # Set $t0 at 90 (Z) 
ADDI $s2, $zero, 10 # Use to test when you reach 10 
SETUP: SB $t0, 0($sp) # Next letter in $t0 
ADDI $sp, $sp, 1 # Increment the stack 
SUB $s2, $s2, $s3 # Decrease the counter by 1 
BEQ $s2, $zero, DONE # Jump to done if $s2 == 0 
J SETUP # If not, jump back to SETUP for loop 
DONE: ADDI $t0, $zero, 0 # Null (0) to terminate string 
SB $t0, 0($sp) # Add null to stack 
ADDI $sp, $sp, -11 # Set up stack to print 
ADDI $v0, $zero, 4 # 4 is for print string 
ADDI $a0, $sp, 0 # Set $a0 to stack pointer for printing 
syscall # Print to the log
```

I've tried to run this in two emulators and the answer seems to be "nothing is printed".  I suppose it's conceivable that's the answer the professor wanted but there are little errors elsewhere on this final so I'm not confident of that.  I guess 90 is ascii code for 'Z' and the idea here was that 'Z' would be printed 10 times.  But what would have had to have actually happened for 'Z' to be printed 10 times? In the videos I've been watching there's always an `li`/`la` pair of instructions to print. Or is this right and is something wrong with the emulators?

And is it correct to say that 
`ADDI $sp, $sp, -11` -> `ADDI $sp, $sp, -101`, 
`ADDI $s2, $zero, 10` -> `ADDI $s2, $zero, 100`, and 
`ADDI $sp, $sp, -11` -> `ADDI $sp, $sp, -101`?

Comment: Why do you believe that -11 would mean -101 and 10 would mean 100? As for _"In the videos I've been watching there's always an li/la pair of instructions to print "_: I'm guessing you've seen people use system call 4 (`print_string`) which is available in simulators like SPIM and MARS. You need to somehow get the value 4 into register `$v0` and the address of the string into register `$a0`, but exactly how you achieve that is largely irrelevant.

Comment: re:"why I believe": I thought that if the program needed to decrement 11 to store 10 Z's it would have to decrement 101 to store 100 Z's.  The second line was doing a comparison to test if we'd reach 10 and now we're trying to get to 100.  And the final line I thought should be changed was just reversing what the first line did.  Does it seem wrong to you or did you just want to understand my reasoning?  I actually realized there was an answer key, and this is indeed what it said.

Comment: @Michael re: printing, thanks! That's good to know. I'm still confused about why this code doesn't log anything in Mars 4.5 or [WeMips](http://rivoire.cs.sonoma.edu/cs351/wemips/) and I wouldn't mind sorting that out.

Comment: Well, have you tried single-stepping through it in the simulator? The fact that you don't have a `.text` directive or a `main` label seems odd. The code you've posted doesn't look like a complete program to me.

Comment: As far as watching YouTube videos could tell me what MIPS conventions are, it doesn't look like a complete program to me either -- I would except "this is wrong" or "this shouldn't work" as an answer.  It runs as expected until I get to the part where it should log, and then it just concludes execution.  (In MARS I'm not sure how to check the values placed in the stack, but everything else seems good.  In WeMIPS I can see the stack.)  I've been able to log in MARS before by copying programs from the YouTube videos.  WeMIPS is currently claiming not to recognize `li` so I can't vouch for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an off by one error.

First, the stack pointer is decremented by 11, then incremented by 10 (one at a time), then decremented by 11 again.  Unbalanced, it doesn't return to where it was given the increment and 2nd decrement.

So, `$sp` is pointing to the null byte just before where the first Z is written — an empty string.

You can confirm this by looking at the address used for the first `SB`, then later the address in `$a0` when printing via syscall #4.

---

As a matter of programming style, on MIPS we generally don't pop the stack and assume our old data is still there if we re-decrement the stack pointer — while this will work on the simulator, some other systems don't make the guarantee that your old data now below the stack pointer comes back when you decrement the stack pointer a second time (it has to do with how interrupts & signals are handled).

A better way to do that is to leave the stack pointer where it is after the first decrement, then copy the stack pointer to another register to use for the byte writes in the loop instead of the stack pointer.

Comment: Thank you!  Changing the second decrement to -10 made it print.  This is an error in the test that the professor wrote, but there are other mistakes so I'm not super surprised.  I will contemplate what you are saying in the second half of your answer and maybe ask a followup question later -- I am two days into trying to learn some MIPS/assembly and it takes me time to absorb things.

Comment: ok, you can look me up on codementor.io tomorrow, if you want a more interactive chat over numerous topics.

Comment: Thanks -- I was able to process what you meant later.  I just needed to take it in in stages.